# Version update in Android for Phonegap

Tags: cordova

I'm developing a phonegap app for android, question is, when google releases new Android version like 5.3,5.3 or 6.0,

1. Does our app works in the new environment ?
2. Do we need to wait for apache to update the cordova version or what can developers do in this scenario ?

please suggest I'm a new bie to Cross-platform app development.

Comment: should work, but usually some things break and you have to wait for a new cordova version that fix the problems or a plugin update. That will happen on native apps too, but instead of waiting for somebody else to fix the problems you have to do it yourself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Old cordova apps made in the times when android 4.0 was the latest version stil work with android 5.0.

As long as you don't intentionally set a maxSdkVersion in config.xml, the app is still supposed to be compatible.

What may go wrong is that cordova apps use the default webview of the OS, so the support of HTML5, javascript or css is different on each android version, and even more when more when the webview engine changes (like when you're on kitkat the default webview now uses chrome instead of old android browser).
Usually, running an app with a "n" target sdk on a "n+1" version of android, the webview should operate in compatibility mode, so there should not be too many issues.

But in any case, to add support for a newer version of android, what you need is not a newer version of cordova, what you need is test your app and upgrade your javascript and sometimes you may need to upgrade some plugins.